# How to reference the correct file when printing a warning in python?

Tags: python, warnings

I just started to use the `warnings` module in python. I'm trying to understand how to reference the correct line in a given file when I issue a warning.

I'm writing a module where some functions can issue warnings, but I would like all warnings to point to the line where they are issued *in scripts where the module was imported*, rather than to a line where they are issued in the module itself. I think I get how the `stacklevel` argument of `warnings.warn` works, but I don't see how to use it with functions of my module that are also used internally, since their stack level might vary.

I will try to make myself clear using an example. Say I write the following module, that I call `testmodule.py`.

```py
import warnings

def f():
    warnings.warn('This is a test warning.', stacklevel=2)

def g():
    f()
```

Then I write the following script.

```
import testmodule as test

test.f()
test.g()
```

If I run this script, the output is

```
"script_filename":3: UserWarning: This is a test warning.
  test.f()
"module_filename":7: UserWarning: This is a test warning.
  f()
```

where `"script_filename"` and `"module_filename"` are the actual names of the files where I saved the script and the module on my computer.

In the above example, both warnings correctly identify the line where `f` is called. However, the warning issued when calling `test.g` points inside of `testmodule`, so it is not useful to a user of the module.  Is there a way to make both of these warnings point to the line where they are issued in the script, and not in the module itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these small changes, I got the exact behaviour you are asking for. Adding arguments to `g()` may not be what you wanted, but I think this is an answer, and may help you understand.

```
import warnings

def f(slevel=2):
    warnings.warn('This is a test warning.', stacklevel=slevel)

def g(i):
    f(i)
```

```
import testmodule  as test

test.f()
test.g(3)
```

Outputs

```
script_filename:3: UserWarning: This is a test warning.
  test.f()
script_filename:4: UserWarning: This is a test warning.
  test.g(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems to be an improvement, but it is not really what I'm looking for. To use this solution, a user of the module would have to know not only that `f` will issue a warning, but also how deep `f` is nested when using `g`. So it would not really be helpful to a user of the module.

Comment: But it would indeed be helpful if `g` didn't take any arguments, but called `f(3)`. I will try to work something out from that. Thank you for your help!